# Form.FormClosing not being fired on when program closes

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I'm trying to detect whether or not the user have save their work before closing the program. I've tried the below coding:

```
void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        MessageBox.Show("Unsave Work");
}
```

But it does not work. Nothing happen when I close the program.

Comment: Are you attaching the event handler?  `Form1.FormClosing += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);`

Comment: Did you check the actual `CloseReason` you are receiving in the event?

Comment: Where to check for Form1.FormClosing += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);

Comment: @maniac84 Start off in the *.designer.cs* file

Comment: How did you add your Form1_FormClosing eventhandler? If through the designer it should work, if you copied/pasted it you will need to add the eventhandler to your form's formclosing event

Comment: I absolutely agree with @MarkHall, You need to check if you have attached the event with the form

Comment: where to check in my form1.designer.cs? Or should I ask where should I put Form1.FormClosing += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);

Comment: @maniac84 I added an answer with an example of how to add it both ways

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two primary ways to add an EventHandler in .Net.

**You can use the designer to add it.**

[image]

**Or you can add it in code**

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FormClosing+=new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
}

void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Unsave Work", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            e.Cancel = true;      
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your way. But there's error saying FormClosingEventHandler could not be found. How?

Comment: @maniac84 Are you using Winforms or Wpf. The above code does work in Winforms. Looking closer your code is Winforms, try adding it the through the property page

Comment: Yes. I've success in showing a message box after press "X" for close program. But I wan the user to choose in the message box, OK for close program and Cancel for stay on the program. How to do it?

Comment: @maniac84 See above edit, I added conditional exit to example

Comment: Yes.Thanks. But for the MessageBoxButtons there's no OKIgnore to choose from. I want a OK button and Ignore button. How do we put it in?

Comment: @maniac84 unfortunately you are limited to what Microsoft gives you for the messagebox button enumeration. You have OkCancel or AbortRetryIgnore. Your only other option would be to make your own MessageBox. You can look at this [MSDN Forum Post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/1086b27f-683c-457a-b00e-b80b48d69ef5) or this [CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17253/A-Custom-Message-Box) on how to do that.

Comment: I see. Then it's OK. I've found out that this OkCancel message box contain "X" close button too. Every time I click this "X" button, it will close. What if I want it to stay in the program instead of close after click "X"?

Comment: @maniac84 When you click the X button it returns a DialogResult of Cancel and will stay in the program. At least that is what the example I gave you is doing.

Comment: But now I got two button, OK and Cancel. OK will stay in the program and Cancel will close the program. If click "X", it will close the program too  same with pressing Cancel but, I want to stay in the program when click "X". How to do it?

Comment: @maniac84 You can not differentiate between the Cancel Button and Clicking the X they return the same DialogResult. You can use YesNo which will disable the X so you do not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

Please first bind your Formclosing function to FormClosing event.

Then check like that below:

```
 void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
                {
                  if(work not saved)//Check your condition
                   {
                     MessageBox.Show("Unsave Work");
                     e.Cancel = true;
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Still not working. Maybe lets get to the basic. How do we show a message box after the user press "X" close program button?

Comment: are you sure Form1.FormClosing += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing); you have this line in form designer cs file?

Answer (score 0):

just ask the user like this:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save your work", "Save work", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                SaveWork();
            }
```

and if you have a way to detect if the user has saved work or not first that would be even better:

```
if (!IsWorkSaved())
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save your work", "Save work", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    SaveWork();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but seems like my program still have not know how to detect when the user press the "X" close button.

Comment: Still not working. Maybe lets get to the basic. How do we show a message box after the user press "X" close program button?

Comment: Yes. I've success in showing a message box after press "X" for close program. But I wan the user to choose in the message box, OK for close program and Cancel for stay on the program. How to do it?